# If I increase the permease enzyme in the Ecoli, will that make it take up lactose even though glucose and galactose are present in more amount?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, ecoli

E coli takes up glucose and galactose on preference because those are easy for it to metabolise.
When there's no glucose and galactose available, it takes up lactose and the lac operon genes produce their products ( gene z codes for enzyme beta galactosidase, gene y codes for permease which helps the bacteria take lactose inside, and gene a codes for transacetylase)
So if I increase the permease enzyme, would it be able to take up lactose even though glucose and galactose is present in more amount?

Comment: Why would you think it would? How much more do you need it to take up? by how much are you overexpressing permease? what are the enzymatic preferences for these various sugars? Write it all out, and I suspect you'll have answered your own question.